# Reverse a string in Java without StringBuilder

Tags: java, string, reverse

I am trying to reverse a string WITHOUT using `StringBuilder`. I have written the below code but it is giving an error as soon as it hits the loop. The error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 16
at lectures.ReverseString.main(ReverseString.java:38)
```

if anyone could tell me why that would be great. FYI I realize this code is not efficient or elegant but I want to know why it isn't working for education.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    //declare variables
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String myString = "";
    int length = 0, index = 0, index2 = 0;

    //get input string
    System.out.print("Enter the string you want to reverse: ");
    myString = input.nextLine();

    //find length of string
    length = myString.length();
    index2 = length;

    //convert to array
    char[] stringChars = myString.toCharArray();
    char[] stringChars2 = stringChars;

    //loop through and reverse order
    while (index<length) {
        stringChars2[index] = stringChars[index2];
        index++;
        index2--;
    }

    //convert back to string
    String newString = new String(stringChars2);

    //output result
    System.out.println(newString);

    //close resources
    input.close();

}
```

Comment: It should be `index2 = length - 1;` remember arrays are indexed from 0 ... length - 1

Comment: try using this: length = myString.length() - 1;

Comment: By the way, if I can give a suggestion, you don't need two arrays to do this. Just use a single array, with two index variables, and swap the first and the last characters, then swap the second and the next to last characters, etc... You keep doing that until your two indexes meet in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last index in an array is **not** `array.length` but `array.length - 1`. Arrays are indexed on a **zero-base**, the first index is `0`.

An array with **two elements** for example has indices `[0]` and `[1]`, not `[2]`.

You access, in the first iteration, `stringChars[index2]` and `index2 = length` where `length = myString.length()`. Thus the `IndexOutOfBoundException`. Carefully read through your code and analyze which indices you need. Create a small example, use some small print statements to debug your code and see which indices you are actually using.

---

Here is an example for a **more compact reverse algorithm**:

```
char[] input = ...

// Iterate in place, from both sides at one time
int fromFront = 0;
int fromEnd = input.length - 1;

while (fromFront < fromEnd) {
    // Swap elements
    char temp = input[fromEnd];
    input[fromEnd] = input[fromFront];
    input[fromFront] = temp;

    fromFront++;
    fromEnd--;
}
```

The algorithm **swaps** the element from the **first** position with the element from the **last** position in place. Then it moves one forward **swapping** the **second** element with the **second to last** and so on. It **stops** once both indices **meet each other** (if `length` is odd) or if the first index gets greater then the other (if `length` is even).

A more easy version, however **without in-place**, is to create a new array:

```
char[] input = ...
char[] reversedInput = new char[input.length];

// Reversely iterate through source
int forwardIndex = 0;
for (int i = input.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    reversedInput[forwardIndex] = input[i];
    forwardIndex++;
}
```